# not able to give filename through a variable in XML::Excel

Tags: perl, automation, perl-module

Not sure if there is any other way or something, but when i pass the filename as :

```
$excel_obj = XML::Excel->new();

$filename = "/tmp/"testresults-2013-07-01.xls"

$excel_obj->parse_doc("testresults-2013-07-01.xls" , {headings => 1});
```

it works, but if i pass :

```
$excel_obj->parse_doc("$filename" , {headings => 1});
```

it does not work
is there any special way to pass a filename through a variable....

Answer (score 1):

When this happens you should try and print out your file name or use debugging mode. 

This line seems to be wrong
   `$filename = "/tmp/"testresults-2013-07-01.xls"` 

You wither need to replace it with this 
     
`$filename = "/tmp/testresults-2013-07-01.xls"` 
removing the double quotes after /tmp/

Comment: that was just a typo... actually it doesnt work if 
$filename = "testresults-2013-07-01.xls" where the file is stored in the current working directory only

Comment: 1. Try and include it in a single quote 2. you can just pipe the file in using <STDIN>